# How to extract intraclass correlation or rho in r?

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to use the between and within effects model specifications. My question is how do I extract the intraclass correlation from these models. In Stata, this output is rho, or the variance due to differences across panels. Below is a copy of what I have using the mtcars dataset. (Hopefully the between and within effects models are correctly specified.)

```
between <- lmer(mpg ~ disp + hp + (1|cyl), mtcars)
summary(between)

within <- felm(mpg ~ disp + hp | factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
summary(within)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question regarding the lmer model specification. By running

```
between.null <- lmer(mpg ~ 1 + (1|cyl), mtcars)
summary(between.null)
```

There are reported both variance of cyl and variance of Residual. Rho should then just be variance of cyl / (variance of cyl + variance of Residual).